# Ubuntu does not boot when external USB HDD is connected

Tags: ubuntu, usb-storage

I am experiencing weird behavior with my Ubuntu machine. Whenever I plug in the external USB HDD (3,5") it does not boot at all - powers up and nothing happens. When I let it boot without the drive and then connect it then all is fine. Disk is visible. Please help.

Comment: In the BIOS boot order, do you have the internal disk drive (the one you *want* to boot from) highest up in the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this issue after few months I found a solution. Issue occured also on that same machine with a different OS (Windows Server 2012 R2). Loosing all hope for a solution I bought a USB 3.0 controller, installed it in PCI slot, plugged the external disk and voila! Issue solved. 
So. If you, reader, have a similar issue, try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Merging Andrew's comment and some clarification:

At boot time AFTER POST and BEFORE the Manufacturer's Logo (s) press one of the following keys -- F2  F11 F12 --normally setup or bios key is mentioned on lower part of screen, once there navigate via arrow keys to `boot` screen and as Andrew mentioned select the desired External drive and move 1) to the top OR 2) above the internal boot drive in the order.

Conversely, you can use (normally F12 key) the `One Time Boot Order`   and select drive desired  next boot (unless repeating process mentioned here will re-run boot from the internal drive)

Comment: Umm... you might want to edit your answer... Q: "**Ubuntu** does not boot when..." A: "BEFORE the **Windows** Logo..." ;) And the OP of course wants the internal drive higher up in the boot order than the USB drive.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, Thanks had misread as a dual boot with external at first

Comment: To answer your posts: internal HDD is the only bootable device, all other are removed from boot order list. OS is installed on internal HDD. External disk is just some data, no executables and stuff - it's WD 2,5TB Desktop.

Comment: @AdrianChrostowski In that case, try adding in "External USB HDD" (that may not be the exact name) and placing it after the internal HDD in the boot order. If that doesn't work, try the external HDD in a different USB socket. And if it still won't work, let us know the make and model of the motherboard, and if the BIOS is the latest version.

Comment: Also brand and model of laptop/pc

Comment: I tried all of the above but no success.
PC model: Lenovo ThinkCentre M57p / 9088 BJG
Motherboard: Lenovo (no specification from sudo lshw)
BIOS: 2RKT38AUS

USB Disk: Seagate Expansion Drive STBV3000200